# How to retrieve files in Subversion (SVN) recently added to the repository?

Tags: svn

How do I get a list of files that have been added recently (not just comitted) to the subversion repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what recent means and if you're using a *nix-styled OS, you could just do...

```
svn log -r{2014-12-01}:{2014-12-03} --verbose | grep '   A'
```

...in this example to find all files that were newly added in the last 3 days.